# Issue with uploading flask python website to google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, error-handling, gcloud

So I am trying to get a pretty simple website uploaded onto google app engine, however I'm getting the error code:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
```

I'm not sure how to get a good view of my project directory, but i have appengine_config.py, app.yaml, requirements.txt all in my root directory, then in /web I have server.py along with my templates and static folder. Within the static folder is about 6000+ images and a json file. 
Here is my current app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /web/static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: /web/server.py
```

appengine_config.py

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

and the requirements.txt:

```
click==6.7
crcmod==1.7
Django==1.11.2
Flask==0.12.2
image==1.5.5
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
numpy==1.13.0
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.1.1
pymongo==3.4.0
pytz==2017.2
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

That should be about it, not using mongodb or anything despite it still being on requirements in case of future use.

Comment: Yes, that could be it.  But I think GAE tells you if there are too many files.  Why would you have BOTH Django and Flask?  Django has a lot of files, so try without that and see if the error persists.

Comment: Ya i'm not sure what's up with my requirements.txt, i use pip freeze but i don't even use half of those imports it doesn't make any sense. Also, there's no way im anywhere near 10000 files

Comment: more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/How_do_you_host_your_website_on_Google_App_Engine